# Delete/Hide margins of a Jtable

Tags: java, swing

I have used a JTable only for the alignement of the values I want to display.
So far I my table looks like this:
[image]

What I want is to delete the margin of the table, so it can't be noticed that it is a table. Is there a way to make this possible?

My code:

```
displayNames = new ArrayList<String>();
displayClasses = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i=0; i<displayName.size(); i++) {
    displayNames.add(displayName.get(i));
    displayClasses.add(classes.get(i));
    }
    Object rowData[][] = { displayNames.toArray(), displayClasses.toArray() };
    Object columnNames[] = displayNames.toArray();
    JTable table = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);
    table.setTableHeader(null);
    table.setShowGrid(false);
    table.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    tablePane = new JScrollPane(table);
    tablePane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(765,40));
    tablePane.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    rightPanel.removeAll();
    rightPanel.updateUI();
    rightPanel.add(tablePane);

public void showGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(leftPanel,BorderLayout.EAST);
        frame.add(listScrollPane,BorderLayout.WEST);
        frame.add(rightPanel);
        frame.setSize(1000,500);
        frame.setLocation(200,100);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Comment: *"I have used a JTable only for the alignement of the values"*  Use a `GridBagLayout` instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [remove cells border in a jtable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167112/remove-cells-border-in-a-jtable)

Comment: I'd be put JTable to container directly, without using JSrollPane, have to override getPrefferedSize from getPreferredScrollableViewportSize()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use setBorder on the JScrollPane

```
tablePane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
```

Answered in more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333623/how-to-get-rid-of-the-border-with-a-jtable-jscrollpane).

Answer (score 0):

```
tablepane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
```

Answer (score 0):

The margin (and border) are showing because you place your table in a JScrollPane.

If you use `rightPanel.add(**table**)`, the margin is gone.

If still want the border, you can manually add a border to the table using `table.setBorder(...).`

By not using the JScrollPane, you obviously will also lose the ability to scroll... I'm not sure if this is a problem for you.

I also agree with Andrew: you shouldn't use a table for this, use GridBagLayout instead.